# How to implement undo/redo of files mapped in a treeview

Tags: c#, undo-redo

Can anyone give an idea of how should I implement undo/redo of cutting/copying/pasting of files (dirs, subdirs) mapped in a treeview in C#?

It would be great to have some code samples.

Comment: What do you mean undo / redo? What are you doing with them?

Comment: Could you please change the topic to something meanfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick linear undo/redo, you can use [Memento pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMemento.aspx) using zip of file as memento.

Answer (score 7):

Consider implementing [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) (GoF):

- Put your actions logic into classes which implement common ICommand {Do(); Undo();} interface.
- On each user action you create object of command requested and initialize it with context parameters like new and old filename.
- Call Do(), put object into stack of completed commands.
- Each command is supplied with context, so by calling Undo() it can reverse changes.
- Consider moving files into temporary folder instead of removals.

Answer (score 5):

Undo / redo is typically implemented using the so-called "command pattern". Search with Google or read the following article:

> http://blogs.vbcity.com/jspano/articles/198.aspx

Comment: +1 for a Good answer, but no idea if it answers the question :)

Comment: I also have no idea whether it answers the question ;-)

Comment: with the new subject, do you understand the question?

Comment: No. What are the actions that you want to do/undo?

Comment: P.S.: Your subject simply repeats now what was already written in the first sentence.

Comment: The TreeView can Cut/Copy/Paste mapped files. Undo/Redo should also be supported. Understood?